# Does rotating light source around the light propagation direction introduce angular momentum to the light field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, optics

If the light source is rotating around the light propagation direction $z$, will the emitted light gain extra (spin or orbit) angular momentum?

Comment: This is probably a good deal harder than it looks. As a starter, see http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Unruh_effect#Rotational_analog_of_the_Unruh_effect

Answer (score 4):

For some types of the source rotating around an axis, the emitted electromagnetic wave can pick up an extra angular momentum
(*rotating around the axis* stated in the question is not completely clear).

First, it should be noted that [spin angular momentum of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light) corresponds to the polarization of the emitted wave, and the (intrinsic) [orbital angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_angular_momentum_of_light) corresponds to the degree of twist or helicity of the wavefronts. Here I have discussed an example of the former.

**Spin angular momentum:**

An example of a rotating radiation source that gives rise to an spin angular momentum is a **rotating dipole** radiator. Consider an infinitesimal dipole located in the x-y plane at the origin:
$$\vec p = \Re\left \{ (p_x, p_y, 0)e^{-i\omega t}  \right \}$$
where $p_x$ and $p_y$ are complex numbers in general.
The electric field (phasor) of this dipole in the far-field (Fraunhoffer) region and on the z axis can easily be obtained as:
$$\vec E (r=0,z)=-\frac{\omega^2 \mu_0 }{4\pi} \frac{e^{ikz }}{z} (p_x\hat x+p_y \hat y)$$
Now, in order to see what happens for a dipole rotating around its axis (here the z-axis), we choose $p_x$ and $p_y$ such that they have $\pi/2$ phase difference and equal magnitude: $p_x=p_0$ and $p_y = p_0e^{i\pi/2}=ip_0$. This would correspond to a dipole rotating around the z-axis. The electric field would become:

$$\vec E (z)=-\frac{\omega^2 \mu_0 }{4\pi} \frac{e^{ikz }}{z}p_0 (\hat x+i \hat y)$$
which has a circular polarization and therefore carries a non-zero **spin** angular momentum. Note that this is caused by the mechanical rotation of the dipole and the radiated far-field of a non-rotating dipole is linearly polarized and does not carry spin angular momentum.
                                                        [image]

This rotating dipole can be used for the simulation of spin-controlled unidirectional photonic waveguiding, which is based on spin-enabled evanescent-wave coupling of the radiated field and the guided wave. Evanescent waves are known to have an [intrinsic transverse spin component](https://www.osapublishing.org/optica/abstract.cfm?uri=optica-3-2-118) coupled to the propagation direction, and therefore the propagation direction can be controlled by the spin of the wave.

The following shows a rotating dipole coupled to a dielectric waveguide (evanescent wave coupling). The propagation direction can be controlled by rotation direction of the dipole.
 (taken from Rodríguez-Fortuño, Francisco J., et al. "Near-field interference for the unidirectional excitation of electromagnetic guided modes." Science 340.6130 (2013): 328-330.)
[image]